# What is the key in Xcode template to define Directory in a target?

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode4.2

What is the key in Xcode template to define Directory in a Target ?

In Target,

- key BuildToolArgsString defines Arguments,
- key BuildToolPath defines Built Tool.

[image]

Comment: As a turn-around, specify `-f ./$(PROJECT_NAME)/makefile all` as Arguments.

Comment: However, the turn-around doesn't allow the click-to-error feature. Clicking on an error from the log navigator or the issue navigator doesn't show up the line of the code, because the path to the file is lost. `$(PROJECT)` acts for the makefile only, not for Xcode in general. So the keyword for Directory is badly needed!

Comment: None of the following keywords works: `BuildToolDirectory` `BuildWorkingDirectory` `BuildToolWorkingDirectory` `BuildToolWorkingDir`