# How to Specify Active Folder for ExternalBuildToolExecution on Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode4, makefile

When using a make for an external build system on Xcode 4x, how to specify the active folder?

The active folder appears on the first line cd/

ExternalBuildToolExecution Action

```
cd /Users/myName/Documents/Xcode/myProject
setenv ACTION
```

By default, it is the folder of the project, i.e. /Users/myName/Documents/Xcode/**myProject**.

However, when the project is created by a template, the Xcode project adds a layer:

- /Users/myName/Documents/Xcode/**myProjec** contains myProject.xcodeproject and another folder named
- /Users/myName/Documents/Xcode/**myProject/myProject** with all the source code inside.

So I need to specify /Users/myName/Documents/Xcode/**myProject/myProject**

An alternative solution would consist on defining the Directory in a Target, but the question [What is the key in Xcode template to define Directory in a Target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240258/what-is-the-key-in-xcode-template-to-define-directory-in-a-target) remains unanswered.

Comment: For an External built system target, the very first line on the log navigator is

`ExternalBuildToolExecution Build
    cd /Users/myName/Documents/Xcode/myProject/myProject`


How to specify it on a template?